# HTML stored in string, convert to HTML with PHP

Tags: php, string

How do you I convert this to HTML?

I'm storing HTML in a string field and I need it to output as HTML (strip the string).

When I output my field I get:

```
"<div class="wrapper">My text</div>"
```

htmlentities just decodes the html chars within the string. I'm lost.

Comment: why and how is it being quoted in the first place. You really haven't provide much for anyone to help with

Comment: It's not quoted. If inspect the output it's in a string.

Comment: `<div class="wrapper">My text</wrapper>` isn't HTML - should be  `<div class="wrapper">My text</div>`

Comment: @Fraser Sorry, that was my error on the example. It's HTML

Answer (score 1):

if you are using JS and jquery

then:

```
var x = "<div class=\"wrapper\">My text</wrapper>";

 $(someSelector).html(x);
```

if it loads dynamically., then use

```
$(document).on('someSelector', 'html', x);
```

this should work., but only if you are using js and jquery

Comment: The field is dynamic so that's not going to work.

Comment: -1 you have the quotes wrong - either `var x = "<div class='wrapper'>My text</wrapper>";` OR `var x = '<div class="wrapper">My text</wrapper>';` ... +1 for fixing :)

Comment: thanks for recognising that part ... i copied that part from question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PHP string of HTML all you need to do is echo it.

```
$html = "<div class='wrapper'>My text</div>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: html cant be used as a variable name... i think because its a reserved keyword

Comment: Yes it can - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: i was looking it more as a js variable., not php... yes you have mentioned it at the top... my bad didn't read that part earlier.